# ClassLoader loadClass throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classloader

```
String pathToJar = "C:\\Users\\dtn\\jb_workspace\\helloworld-mdb\\target\\jboss-as-helloworld-mdb.war";

URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:///" + pathToJar+"!/") };
URLClassLoader urlcl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
urlcl.loadClass("org.jboss.as.quickstarts.mdb.HelloWorldTopicMDB");
```

The exception I got is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.quickstarts.mdb.HelloWorldTopicMDB
```

When I investigated into the problem, I saw the **HelloWorldTopicMDB.class** file is stored inside WEB-INF/classes.

Can that somehow the root of the problem ? Since I tried with other jar file, with package name at the root of the jar directory structure, there is no error.

Thanks very much for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a proper war file, compiled classes are always in WEB-INF/classes, and jars needed at runtime are in WEB-INF/lib.

That is definitely the cause of your problem. This [resource](http://ripper234.com/p/warclassloader-load-your-classes-straight-from-a-war/) should help you load classes from within the war file.

I must say though this seems rather unorthodox. Usually web servers load classes from war files. Can I ask why you are doing this?

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. I want to get information from the war file (annotations, method name ..) and display it. So I need to load classes of war file.